# How to use multiple router objects in ember.js

Tags: ember.js, ember-old-router

I'm still new to ember.js but one part of the framework that I'm yet to see at scale is the basic Ember Router. In a small single page app you have just one router that manages all the state / routes / etc. But as your app grows how do you manage complexity if the pattern seems to focus around just 1 object?

Curious if this is just something I've overlooked or if this is assumed to be a massive global state management object like the AppDelegate in iOS for example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know if my way is the generally accepted best practice, but I do know that when the router gets big that it should be split into multiple files. I accomplished that like this:

#### app_router.js

```js
App.Router = Ember.Router.extend({
  enableLogging: true,
  root: Ember.Route.extend({
    route: '/',
    index: Ember.Route.extend({
      route: '/',
      redirectsTo: 'app.index'
    }),
    app: Ember.Route.extend({
      route: '/app',
      showProfile: Ember.Route.transitionTo("user.index"),
      index: Ember.Route.extend({
        route: '/',
        redirectsTo: 'items'
      }),
      items: App.ItemsRoute,
      item: App.ItemRoute,
      users: App.UsersRoute,
      user: App.UserRoute,
      hashtagbrand: App.HashtagbrandRoute
    })
  })
});
```

#### items_router.js

```js
App.ItemsRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  route: '/items',
  connectOutlets: function(router, items) {
    router.get("applicationController").connectOutlet({
      name: 'carouselContainer',
      outletName: 'carousel',
      context: App.store.find(App.Item)
    });
    router.get("applicationController").connectOutlet({
      name: 'logo',
      outletName: 'header'
    });
  },
  index: Ember.Route.extend({
    route: '/'
  })
}); 


App.ItemRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  route: '/items/:id',
  //...
  index: Ember.Route.extend({
    route: '/'
    //...
  })
});
```